# No component blocks in QuickFIX/N and QuickFix c++

Tags: quickfix, quickfixj

In QuickFIX/J, it implements the component blocks, such as quickfix.fix43.component.Instrument.

Component blocks do not exist in QuickFIX/N and neither in QuickFix c++ version. Why is it so? Is there any quick way to generate the classes in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QF just "inlines" them (so to speak) into the message structure.

All the fields are there.  QF just doesn't bother to wrap them in some kind of unnecesary component container.